# Can I use a LED bulb with an Alba Halo6 standing lamp?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, lamp

I'm using an Alba HALO6 floor-standing lamp: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Alba-HALO6-Halogen-Floor-Black/dp/B000KTCBXA, with a halogen R7s bulb.

Can someone tell me if I can use this with a dimmable LED bulb, or how I could verify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find a bulb (tube) that fits, there shouldn’t be a problem. Since it’s an open fixture, there’s no issue with heat build up. The problem is that most LED replacement for halogen tube-type bulbs are thicker than the original halogen and so they may not fit over the reflector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed now that I'm shopping for LED bulbs I see they look bulkier than the halogen tube, and the enclosure is pretty narrow, so I'll try to measure for fit before I'll buy a LED one.